# JavaFX Full Screen Exclusive Mode

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, fullscreen, kiosk-mode

I am making a JavaFX kiosk application that needs to take full control of the screen and disallow closing, minimising, and certain keypresses. I was wondering is there a way to make a JavaFX application run in full screen exclusive mode, if not are there any alternatives that could achieve the same goal. I have tried using:

```
stage.setFullScreen(true);
```

which does successfully make the application full screen, however the user can still exit the application or exit the full screen.

Comment: You could try to override the default-handlers for the actions (exit, minimising). Check out this link for an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17003906/prevent-cancel-closing-of-primary-stage-in-javafx-2-2

Answer (score 1):

Handle close events.

following code may help!

// Set plat params
Platform.setImplicitExit(false);

```
primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(WindowEvent event) {
// deque it
        event.consume();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue recently, hopefully you figured it out (I wouldn't wait 4 years for an answer).

If not:

Before you make a call to `stage.show()` you need to call `setFullScreenExitKeyCombination` and pass `KeyCombination.NO_MATCH` as the only parameter.

so for example...

```
stage.setFullScreenExitKeyCombination(KeyCombination.NO_MATCH);
stage.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

This will prevent closing and de-fullscreening w/ESC (but still leave you with a backdoor-y way to remove fullscreen - Shift+PAUSE or F13):

```
scene.setOnKeyPressed((event) ->
{
  if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.PAUSE && event.isShiftDown())
    stage.setFullScreen(!stage.isFullScreen());
});
stage.setOnCloseRequest(Event::consume);
stage.setFullScreenExitKeyCombination(new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.F13));
```

In order to close your application you'd have to add a `Platform.exit()` on some command.