# Run JavaFX Screen in Kiosk Mode

Tags: java, javafx

Is there a way to run a JavaFX app in kiosk mode (full screen), this code does full screen:

```
Scene scene = new Scene(root);
stage.setMaximized(true);
```

However, the taskbar of the OS is still visible. How to achieve the mode similar to Google Chrome kiosk mode where it can cover the whole screen?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaFX Full Screen Exclusive Mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22122127/javafx-full-screen-exclusive-mode)

Comment: @DanO This is not a duplicate since that SO question does not answer the problem in this question

Comment: Did you look at the [documentation for Stage](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html) before asking this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This consumes any close request attempts, overrides the exit with `esc` key and sets full screen to true.

```
stage.setFullScreen(true);
stage.setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(WindowEvent event) {
        //Handle
        event.consume();
    }
});
primaryStage.setFullScreenExitKeyCombination(KeyCombination.NO_MATCH);
```