# Disabling Windows button using Java for JavaFX application

Tags: java, windows, javafx

I am developing JavaFX application and its steps involved are these:

1. Application once launched should terminate all user running processes
2. Application should open in Full-Screen Mode.
3. Application should only be closed programmtically when user completes the test or perform any unwanted   action.

Everything is working fine, but the issue starts when application is launched and user enters the Windows button, application focus is lost start menu is opened. How can I override this issue initial code for my application is:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCombination;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;
import org.dc_proctoring.dc_v_1.UtilityClasses.OSOperations;
import org.dc_proctoring.dc_v_1.UtilityClasses.ResourceLoaders;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

public class HomeApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String osName = System.getProperty("os.name");
        System.out.println("osName = " + osName);
        if(osName.startsWith("Windows")){

            // Terminate all user processes currently running.
            Thread killUserProcessesThread = new Thread(OSOperations::killAllProcesses);
            killUserProcessesThread.start();
            loadApplicationForWindows(stage);

        }else if(osName.startsWith("Linux")){
            System.out.println("Linux System detected");
        } else if(osName.startsWith("Mac")){
            System.out.println("Mac System detected");
        }
    }

    private static void loadApplicationForWindows(Stage stage){
        Scene scene = getScene();

        stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
        stage.setTitle("DC Proctoring Application");
        Image icon = new Image(ResourceLoaders.loadResources("logo.jpg"));
        stage.getIcons().add(icon);
        stage.setOnCloseRequest(event -> {
            if (stage.isFullScreen()) {
                event.consume(); // Consume the event to prevent minimization
                stage.setFullScreen(true); // Exit full screen mode instead
            }
        });
        stage.setFullScreen(true);
        stage.setResizable(false);
        stage.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        stage.setFullScreenExitHint("You can't escape it.");
        stage.setFullScreenExitKeyCombination(KeyCombination.NO_MATCH);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    private static Scene getScene() {
        Group group = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(group, Color.WHITE);
        scene.setOnDragOver(dragEvent -> {
            System.out.println("dragEvent = " + dragEvent);
            System.out.println("dragEvent Called");
        });
        scene.setOnKeyPressed(keyEvent -> {
            KeyCode keyCode = keyEvent.getCode();
            if(keyCode == KeyCode.UNDEFINED){
                keyEvent.consume();
            }
            else if (keyCode.toString().equals("WINDOWS")){
                Platform.exit();
            }
        });
        return scene;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are trying to re-invent kiosk mode. Probably worth looking into it. Everything else is done using user permissions so user can bypass it easily. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/kiosk-single-app

Comment: [You can possibly do this using JNA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7793900/4725875).

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Run JavaFX Screen in Kiosk Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40540411/run-javafx-screen-in-kiosk-mode) (though the current answer there doesn't address your question as fully as the official info on Windows Kiosk mode from Microsoft that bendem links to in comments).  There is also related info on running [JavaFX on a Raspberry Pi in Kiosk mode](https://pi4j.com/getting-started/fxgl/kiosk-mode/), though I understand that is not your environment and may not be relevant for you.