# How to stop a stage from closing when user selects close button?

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I can add this code to hook into the stage close event:

```
stage.setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {
    public void handle(WindowEvent we) {
        System.out.println("Stage is closing");
        // but wait! I don't want it to close!
    }
});
```

but how do I stop the stage from closing?

Comment: For [example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17003906/230513).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17016665/6586867) comment:

```
Platform.setImplicitExit(false);

primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(WindowEvent event) {
        event.consume();
    }
});
```