# Display a confirmation dialogue when the user try to exit the application (Press X button)

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I want to modify the default exit procedure in my javafx application to display a confirmation dialogue to the user. The confirmation dialogue will exit the application if the user chooses OK and will keep the application running when user chooses Cancel.

What should I do to make this in javaFX?

Comment: I tried overriding the stop() method in the main class but it still closes the application even before the confirmation Prompt is displayed

Comment: I found the best answer is in this thread:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13727314/prevent-or-cancel-exit-javafx-2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
primaryStage.addEventFilter(WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSE_REQUEST, e->{
    e.consume();
    Popup popup = new Popup();
    HBox buttons = new HBox();
    Button close = new Button("close");
    Button cancel = new Button("cancel");
    buttons.getChildren().addAll(close,cancel);
    buttons.setPadding(new Insets(5,5,5,5));
    popup.getContent().add(buttons);
    popup.show(primaryStage);
    close.setOnAction(ex -> {
        Platform.exit();
    });
    cancel.setOnAction(ec -> {
        popup.hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: it worked after the edit you made. thank you very much.

Comment: No problem. Adapted the code from another program that had a similar feature, but was not in my style so almost forgot to put the edit. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 2):

You can use Alert since 8.40

```
stage.setOnCloseRequest(evt -> {
    Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
    alert.setTitle("Confirm Close");
    alert.setHeaderText("Close program?");
    alert.showAndWait().filter(r -> r != ButtonType.OK).ifPresent(r->evt.consume());
});
```

Comment: I would have shown an example using an alert however, I have had experiences with it glitching before and chose the safer option.

Answer (score 1):

I Followed this approach...

**After creating my stage I use this code to launch a popup and exit...**

```
stage.setOnCloseRequest((WindowEvent arg0) -> {
        arg0.consume();
        Alert exitAlert = new Alert(AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
        exitAlert.setTitle("Exit Confirmation");
        exitAlert.setHeaderText(null);
        exitAlert.setContentText("Do you really need to exit ?");

        ButtonType yesBtn = new ButtonType("Yes", ButtonData.YES);
        ButtonType noBtn = new ButtonType("No", ButtonData.NO);

        exitAlert.getButtonTypes().setAll(yesBtn, noBtn);
        exitAlert.initOwner(getScene().getWindow());
        exitAlert.showAndWait();
        if (exitAlert.getResult().getButtonData() == ButtonData.YES) {
            Platform.exit();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
```